# pointer to pointer assignment in c

Tags: c, pointers

Why this code isn't working?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv){

    char * new;
    new = malloc(10);
    const char * s1 = "hello";

    while(*s1){
        *new++ = *s1++;
    }
    printf("%s",new);

    return 0;
}
```

I ran the gdb and found that *s1 is not assigned to the *new. why?

Comment: You've modified `new` in your loop, so it no longer points to the beginning of the block you allocated -- it points to the character after the last one you copied in.  You also haven't copied the null terminator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`new` is pointing to one byte past the last element of whatever was copied over from `s1`. You should pass the pointer to the first element of `new` to get the entire text.

Another problem is that you are *not* copying over the `\0` from `s1` to `new`. You should put a `\0` at the end of `new` before trying to print it. Otherwise you are invoking [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You might do something like this and check:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv){

    char * new, *new2;
    new = malloc(10);
    new2 = new;
    const char * s1 = "hello";
    while(*s1){
        printf("%c\n", *s1); // the \0 is *not* appended
        *new++ = *s1++;
    }
    *new = '\0';
    printf("%s\n",new2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also remember that `new` is probably not your best choice of names (though legal) because `new` is what allocates in C++. `char *p = new;` and operating on `p` works as well.

Comment: you are right @DavidC.Rankin will change.. also lawyer and a programmer man you are an inspiration! thank you

Comment: Nope, just bipolar (left brain/right brain thing `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin having bipolar makes you multi talented what ?? lol

Answer (score 1):

Because the `new` is pointing to the location one after the last character copied from `s1` to `new`.

You can do:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv){

    char *new, *tmp;
    new = malloc(10);
    if (new == NULL){
        printf ("Failed to allocate memory");
        return -1;
    }

    const char * s1 = "hello";
    tmp = new;   //take a temporary pointer and point it to new
    while(*s1){
       *tmp++ = *s1++;    //use tmp to copy data
    }
    *tmp = '\0';
    printf("%s",new);
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: ah i want to accept both answers! thanks for ur time ppl